# Proof-verification: $(x_n)$ bounded and $y_n \to 0$ implies $(x_ny_n)\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Proof-verification: $(x_n)$ bounded and $y_n \to 0$ implies
>   $(x_ny_n)\to 0$

**My attempted proof:**

Let $(x_n)$ be bounded, hence there exists $A\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_n|\leq A$. Furthermore let $y_n$ be a null-sequence; thus for an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ there exisits $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|y_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

$$|x_n\cdot y_n|\leq |A\cdot y_n|=|A|\cdot |y_n|<|A|\cdot \varepsilon$$ Since $\varepsilon$ does not depend on $|A|$, one can conclude that the claim is indeed true. $\Box$

is that okay?

Comment: "such that $|y_n|$" was a typo for "such that $|y_n|<\epsilon$", right?

Comment: Yeah, thanks it's been fixed.

Comment: Yes you can argue that for all Ɛ>0 there exists an N such that |y_n|<Ɛ/A. From here you can get the definition of the limit (of (x_ny_n) )being zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we correct the obvious typo then this is fine; exactly this sort of argument is given all the time.

But it's somewhat "informal", in that the conclusion does not look like what's required by the definition. A more formally correct version would read "Since $y_n\to0$, given $\epsilon>0$  there exists $N$ such that $|y_n|<\epsilon/A$ for all $n>N$..."

So whether it's actually "right" depends on the context. In a research paper, or some other context where the point is to convince the  reader it's true, what you wrote is fine - people *do* write this sort of thing all the time. In a calculus class it's different - there the point is to convince the reader that *you* know exactly how to prove it, and in that context you're much better off getting a literal $|x_ny_n|\dots<\epsilon$ at the end.

**Note:** Of course @pre-kidney is also correct in saying that the last sentence is missing the point; that issue doesn't come up if we change it as suggested.

Comment: English is not my native language, i suppose it is more formal in my mothers language.

Comment: You are being over-pedantic. Everybody knows that $A\varepsilon$ is as good as $\varepsilon$, if $A$ is a positive constant.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic No, that has nothing to do with it. According to the definition you're required to show there exists $N$ such that $|x_ny_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. If "$|x_ny_n|<A\epsilon$" is the same as "$|x_ny_n|<\epsilon$" in your native language you need a different language.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will fix that.

Comment: @uniquesolution I know everyone knows that. Everyone also knows that if $x_n$ is bounded and $y_n\to0$ then $x_ny_n\to0$. So saying "Everyone knows this" would be a sufficient proof? ("Pedantic": Did you see the first sentence in my answer? If I'd  said simply that the proof was wrong _that_ would be pedantic...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks good except the last sentence - the crucial thing is not that $\epsilon$ does not depend on $|A|$, but rather that for every $\delta>0$ we can choose $N$ sufficiently large such that the corresponding $\epsilon$ satisfies $|A|\epsilon<\delta$. That is what is required to show the convergence.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, your proof is okay. Some other users obviously don't share my view. It is my personal opinion they are being too pedantic. I find it amusing that of all answers, this one of mine is so vehemently downvoted and opted for deletion. C'est la vie.

Comment: I didn't downvote you (and don't downvote answers), but I think that the reason you were downvoted is probably because your answer, as initially written, could've been left as a comment (and in its current form has a somewhat combative tone).

Comment: I agree @cmk. It somehow felt like he was teasing me. I am at the beginning of my math career and proving things formally is quite new for me.

Comment: @cmk - Thank you for your comment. The OP has asked a question. I have answered the question. A comment is a comment, and an answer is an answer. It is a typically condescending behaviour of some users of this site to decide for others that their answers are not good enough to be called an answer. As a matter of principle, I shall leave this answer here, for it is a perfectly good answer. It may be a wrong one, but not for the reason that it should be a comment.

I have no opinion as to whether it is combative or not.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic - Not at all teasing. Why would I bother teasing you? Would you feel better if I deleted the "elementary result" part? It is after all, very very elementary, and your argument is correct after all, even though some of the pedantic guys think you should have started with $\varepsilon/A$ only to multiply out the $A$ and remain with the holy $\varepsilon$ at the end.

Comment: I know, but it isn't really motivating knowing that this is "baby stuff" :D Which I know it is.

Comment: There, it is no longer baby stuff.

Comment: I actually up-voted your answer.

Comment: Thank you, but the righteous leftists are very determined :-)